# I can't not chain a promise to execute Uncaught TypeError: dispatch(...).then is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to use "useDispatch" in react hooks. I want to execute a promise only if the function goes through. So if the user login correctly with user and password correct then it console.log"sucess" but if it doesnt it console.log"not sucess" but I keep getting an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: dispatch(...).then is not a function
```

LOGIN COMPONENT

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useHistory, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import { login, clearErrors } from '../../actions/session_actions';
import { closeModal } from '../../actions/modal_actions';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import logo from '../../assets/images/crm_logo.svg';


const LoginForm = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();
    const [ email, setEmail ] = useState('');
    const [ password, setPassword ] = useState('');
    const errors  = useSelector(state => state.errors.session);

      // useEffect(() => {
      //   if (errors.length) dispatch(clearErrors());
      // }, []);

    const updateEmail = e => setEmail(e.target.value);
    const updatePassword = e => setPassword(e.target.value);

    const closeX = () => dispatch(closeModal());

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const user = {
            email, 
            password
        };

       dispatch(login(user))
        .then(() => console.log('login sucess'))
        .error(err => console.log('not sucess'))
       
    }

    return (
      <LForm>
        {console.log(errors)}
            <LogoImage>
              <img src={logo} alt="" />
            </LogoImage>
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              <input value={email} onChange={updateEmail} placeholder='Email'/>
            </label>
            <label>
              
              <input value={password} onChange={updatePassword} type='password' placeholder='Password'/>
            </label>
            <input type='submit' value='Log In' />
          </Form>
      </LForm>
    );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

ACTION

```
const loginUser = currentUser => {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_USER,
        currentUser
    }
};
```

Comment: `dispatch` function is sync . you can write your code below it , it will get executed after the `dispatch` function gets completed.

Comment: @ShoyebMemon I tried adding async and await but it doesnt work

Comment: you don't have to even write async and await . `disptach` is synchronous in nature . just write your console directly below the `disptach()` .

Comment: if you want to check if your user has been successfully stored or not , use the `useSelector` to get the value of the `user`.  write an if else condition and put your both console's accordingly.

Comment: `dispatch` can only be awaited or chained from if using redux middleware that handles asynchronous actions. Your `loginUser` doesn't appear to be an asynchronous action creator. Just use a selector and check the state value after it updates if you are just wanting to log the value out.